# SeleniumWebdriver = How to refresh browser and wait for specific email to be arrive based on no timeline

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying a few selenium script learning activity and stuck at where one of my application to generate an email using which i've to proceed further and thing is how keep waiting for a specific email title to be appeared in the inbox and there's no timeline sometime it do appeared within 2 min of time or sometime it takes 4 minutes.
I've tried following sample code using which I'm able to proceed ahead if email triggers within this time otherwise the script is getting failed.

```
    int refreshCount = 5;
                List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(locator);
                for (int i =0; i<refreshCount; i++)
                    {
                    if(element.size() >0 ){
                        ((WebElement) element).click();
                } else
                    {
                        do{
                            driver.navigate().refresh();
                        }
                        while(!driver.findElement(locator).isDisplayed());
                        }
            }
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System. Print("Unable to locate the email with titled :" +locator);
                
            }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would also advise to put some sleep in that for loop, and see if that works